# ReferenceError: _ is not defined on an array .map() call

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, next.js, lodash, ecmascript-5

I'm getting a "ReferenceError: _ is not defined" on a .map call like this:

```
arr.map(async (elem) => {
...
});
```

There doesn't appear to be any explicit mention of "_" anywhere here. When I look at the source of the error, I see:

```
eval
webpack-internal:///./src/components/admin/NameOfMyFile.tsx (115:51)
step
node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js (102:0)
Object.eval [as next]
node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js (83:45)
asyncGeneratorStep
node_modules/@swc/helpers/src/_async_to_generator.mjs (3:0)
_next
node_modules/@swc/helpers/src/_async_to_generator.mjs (25:0)
eval
node_modules/@swc/helpers/src/_async_to_generator.mjs (32:0)
```

The only lead I have here is that it seems to be trying to use something in tslib.es6.js but in my tsconfig.json, my "target" is "es5". Not really sure if this plays a role or just a red herring.

I'm on Next.js and this is done on the client side. (On the server side, it doesn't appear to have any problems)

Would love some help here if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: ES5 doesn't have native promises, so the compiler has to do some extra steps there to translate ES6 async code to ES5. It seems there's an error in that process. Not sure how to fix it, but if you're able to natively target ES6 instead (i.e. target non-legacy browsers), that should bypass the error.

Comment: Maybe you can also look at your built code and see if there is any `_` there.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps, I had this problem too, and it was because I was nesting `await`s, something like this:

```
const resp = await api(...., {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${await getToken()}` 
  }
})
```

Moving the `await getToken()` outside like so:

```
const token = await getToken()
const resp = await api(...., {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` 
  }
})
```

That made the issue go away. I could have sworn I've done this nested await thing before, but I haven't had time so far to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr **Try upgrading Next.js**

I experienced something similar. This issue started happening today when I upgraded the caniuse-lite db (`npx browserslist@latest --update-db`).

[image: stack trace]

(I do have a somewhat of an `await` within an `await`)

The app isn't on the latest Next.js version, so I upgraded and the issue went away.

Some notes:

- I upgraded Next.js from `12.3.0` to `12.3.4` so the fix is somewhere in patch 1, 2, 3 or 4
- If I revert to the previous version of "caniuse-lite" the issue goes away
- I couldn't find anything related on the Next.js GitHub (issues, nor discussions)